# SMS from a website

Tags: email, sms

I've been looking into how to code a website (through php or javascript) to send an SMS message to some friends' and my phones. The idea is that we'd like to get daily reminders with a message saying "posture" at some point during the day while we're awake to remind us to sit up straight, not slouch, etc.

So far, I've only found answers that seem to show how to send an email to the website owner (http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/mail.htm) using forms or that use other API's and/or services.

I know that each phone has its own unique "email address" provided through the phone company so that would be an easy matter to figure out. The problem I'm having is how to send an email from the site itself. Is there a way to do this through php or javascript, and automatically so I don't have to manually send the message every day? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*"I know that each phone has its own unique "email address" provided through the phone company so that would be an easy matter to figure out."* **NO.**

*"The problem I'm having is how to send an email from the site itself. Is there a way to do this through php or javascript, and automatically so I don't have to manually send the message every day?"*

Are you just talking about automating a message on a daily basis? Check out http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/ - really all i did was google php and scheduled interval.  I'm certainly not going to say how to have php email somebody, as there's got to be 1,000 other posts on the topic.

if you want to actually setup SMS via a real cell network, there are paid API's + servers that tie into the network that hook you up. Search for them. There's a ton, and each one provides slightly different services at different rates. Look em up.